# Uniform convergence from pointwise convergence for uniform Lipshitz functions

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence, lipschitz-functions

I would like to prove or give a counterexample for the following statement:

Let $(S,d)$ be a complete and seperable space. We define:
$$
\mathcal{P}^1(S) := \{P: \mathcal{B}_S \rightarrow [0,1] \mid P \mbox{ probability measure, }\exists a \in S: \int d(x,a) P(dx) < \infty\}
$$
Let $(P_n)_n, P$ all be in $\mathcal{P^1}(S)$ and suppose we have for any $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\forall x,y \in S: |f(x) - f(y)| \leq d(x,y): \int f dP_n \rightarrow \int f dP$ then we also have $\sup_{f \in L^1(S,\mathbb{R})} \left| \int f dP_n - \int f dP \right| \rightarrow 0$.
where $L^1(S,\mathbb{R})$ is the collection of Lipschitz functions with Lischitz constant 1.

I have both tried proving and disproving this statement, as a counterexample I tried to take $S := \mathbb{R}$ and $P(\{n\}) := \frac{1}{2^n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and taking $P_n(\{n\}) := 1$ and stuff like that but it didn't work out (I also tried to fiddle with uniform distributions but this didn't give me a counterexample either.

Then I tried to prove it, by regularity we can find a compact set $K$ for which $P(S\setminus K)$ is ''small enough'' then we can get the uniform convergence on $K$ but the problem is that I can't bound $\sup_n P_n(S\setminus K)$, for this it would seem that I need that $(P_n)_n$ is tight but I don't think I have this..

Comment: Do you assume that the Lipschitz $f $s are bounded?  Otherwise, you can't even write down the integral in question  in general.

Comment: You are right I meant to write that we restrict ourselves to the $P$ for which $\int d(x,a) P(dx)$ is finite for some (and thus all) $a\in S$

Comment: same goes for the $P_n$, but I editted the question, it should make sense now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we want to assume maybe that $S$ is locally compact and the measures are regular; with the problem as stated I don't see why for example there exists a compact $K$ with $P(S\setminus K)$ small.

The argument might use a little cleaning up, but I think it's right:

We need the existence of  a "Lebesgue number" for an open cover of a compact subset of a metric space. There's been some confusion about that, since the lemma is sometimes stated instead for an open cover of a compact metric space. So:

Lemma: Suppose $K$ is a compact subset of a metric space and $O$ is an open cover of $K$. There exists $r>0$ so that for every $x\in K$ there exists $V\in O$ with $B(x,r)\subset V$.

Proof: Define $\phi:K\to(0,1]$ by saying $\phi(x)$ is the supremum of the $r\in(0,1]$ such that there exists $V\in O$ with $B(x,r)\subset V$. It's clear that $|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|\le d(x,y)$, so $\phi$ is continuous. So there exists $\delta>0$ with $\phi(x)\ge\delta$ for all $x\in K$. Let $r=\delta/2$. QED.

Corollary: If $K$ is a compact subset of a locally compact metric space then there exists $r>0$ such that $K_r=\bigcup_{x\in K}\overline{B(x,r)}$ is compact.

Proof: Cover $K$ by finitely many balls with compact closure. Let $r$ be a Lebesgue number for this cover. QED.

Fix $a\in S$. Let $F$ be the space of all $f$ with $d(f(x),f(y))\le d(x,y)$ and let $F_0$ be the space of all $f\in F$ with $f(a)=0$.

Suppose the conclusion fails. Replacing $(P_n)$ by a subsequence, there exists $\epsilon>0$ and $f_n\in F_0$ such that $$|\int f_ndP_n-\int f_ndP|\ge100\epsilon$$for all $n$. Again taking a subsequence, we can assume that $f_n(x)$ converges as $n\to\infty$ for all $x$ in our countable dense subset of $S$. The equicontinuity shows that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x\in S$, and in fact $f_n\to f$ uniformly on compact sets.

Let $C=\int d(x,a)dP$. Choose $K$ compact so $$\int_{S\setminus K}d(x,a)dP<\epsilon.$$
Restricting to $n$ large enough we can assume that $$\int d(x,a)dP_n<C+\epsilon.$$ Choose $r>0$ so that $K_r$ is compact, as in the corollary.

Now, there exists a Lipschitz function $\phi$ which equals $1$ on $K$, vanishes off $K_r$, and satisfies $0\le \phi\le 1$ everywhere. Considering the product $\phi(x)d(x,a)$ shows that $$\liminf \int_{K_r}d(x,a)dP_n\ge \int\phi(x)d(x,a)dP\ge\int_K d(x,a)dP.$$ Hence if $n$ is large enough we have $$\int_{S\setminus K_r}d(x,a)dP_n<2\epsilon.$$

Now since $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $K_r$ we have $$|\int_{K_r}|f_n-f|dQ<\epsilon$$if $n$ is large enough, for $Q=P$ and also for $Q=P_n$ If $g\in F_0$ then $|g(x)|\le d(x,a)$ and hence $$\int_{S\setminus K_r}|g|dQ<\epsilon$$again for $Q=P$ or $Q=P_n$, by the inequalities above. Hence $$\int_{S\setminus K_r}|f-f_n|dQ<8\epsilon.$$So $$\int_S|f-f_n|dQ<10\epsilon$$for large $n$.

Finally, if $n$ is large enough we have $$|\int fdP_n-\int fdP|<\epsilon.$$And if I didn't leave anything out, the triangle inequality plus the above now contradict $|\int f_ndP_n-\int f_ndP|>100\epsilon$.

Comment: Hello, I'm going to read your answer now but I'd first like to explain the reasoning why I find this $K$:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary
Let $(x_k)_k$ be a countable dense subset of $S$ then we have for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0: S = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty B(x_k,\frac{1}{n})$, thus we find some every $n$ some $k_n$ for which $P(\bigcup_{k=1}^{k_n} B(x_k,\frac{1}{n})) \geq 1- \varepsilon/2^n$. Now we take:
$$
K := \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0} \bigcup_{k=1}^{k_n} B(x_k,\frac{1}{n}), 
$$
this set is then compact with $P(S \setminus K) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \varepsilon/2^n = \varepsilon$.

Comment: About the lemma: 
You use that $r$ is a Lebesgue number which exists for any open cover of $K$,  but I would believe that you then only have that $B(x,r) \cap K$ is contained in one of these sets (as we use this Lebesgue number lemma only for the subspace $K$), and then I don't see why we're able to say something about the compactness of $B(x,r)$. Thx for the response and Merry X-Mas btw :)!

Using a totally different approach I have already solved this problem btw, but it would be nice to have a different approach to the problem :)! I was able to reduce th problem and then someone helped me

Comment: On:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544955/convergence-of-int-f-dp-n-to-int-f-dp-for-all-lipschitz-functions-f-impl

Comment: @HolyMonk Since $K$ is compact and $S$ is locally compact there exist balls $B_1,\dots B_N$ such that each $B_j$ has compact closure and $K\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^NB_j$. If $r$ is a Lebesgue number then $K_r\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^NB_j$. But $\bigcup_{j=1}^N\overline{B_j}$ is compact and $K_r$ is closed, hence $K_r$ is compact.

Comment: @HolyMonk In your first comment, where you say "this set is then compact": I don't see why that set is compact. (Without any extra assumptions on $S$.)

Comment: @HolyMonk Never mind, I _do_ see why that set is compact. At least if we say $B(x,r)$ is the _closed_ ball throughout.

Comment: Yea I should have written $\overline{B(x_k,\frac{1}{n}))}$ that was sloppy I apologize.

Ok, so for the existence of the Lebesgue number we take as compact set $\bigcup_{j=1}^N \overline{B_j}$ but then what is our open cover? We can take $\{B_j \mid j = 1,\dots, N\}$ but this doesn't cover this set. (I first thought that we took $K$ as compact set for which these $B_j$ are a cover but then I have the problem I stated above. I'm sorry for my not understanding, I've also read the rest of the proof which seems to be clear to me!

Comment: In the lemma the $B_j$ are _open_ balls such that $K\subset V=\bigcup_jB_j$ and such that $\overline B_j$ is compact. If $r>0$ is a Lebesgue number for that open cover then for every $x\in K$ there exists $j$ with $B(x,r)\subset B_j$. Now $K_r=\bigcup_{x\in K}\overline{B(x,r)}$ is closed (this follows from compactness of $K$) and $K_r\subset\bigcup_j\overline B_j$, hence $K_r$ is compact.

Comment: But if you use the compactness of $K$ to get this Lebesgue number then you ought to take the balls $B(x,r) \cap K$ I think? Since we are then working in the subspace $K$?

Comment: Oh. The lemma asserting the existence of a Lebesgue number is sometimes stated for an open cover of a compact metric space. There's a version, with the same proof, for a compact subset of a metric space. I'll edit my answer...

Comment: Ow, okay I always used it for a compact metric space! So that's nice to know! :) Thanks nice proof, I don't know if I should be the one to accept your answer since the bounty isn't from me!

The nice thing about your proof is that I think it can be adapted to partly solve:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545832/disprove-sup-f-in-2l1s-mathbbr-limsup-sup-f-in-f-int-f-dp-n

I will be looking into that after my exams probably :)!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe that what you're supposed to do is accept it or not just as if there were no bounty. I'm not concerned about the points, I thought it was a good question. Because usually when I "see" "why" something is true that means I see how to prove it - here I "saw" very clearly why it was true but it took a few hours to translate that into a proof. Never did quite formulate the fact that seemed obvious: In some sense given any bit of the mass of $P$ there must be a similarly-sized bit of $P_n$ nearby...

Comment: All righty I did! Thanks! And also thanks to Normal Human for putting a bounty on my question!